# Differences between g++ on Ubuntu versus OS X Homebrew

Tags: c++, g++, homebrew

I'm working on a standalone project written in C++; it doesn't call on any third-party libraries or any external dependencies - i.e. it is completely self-contained. It is primarily developed on Ubuntu.

I have a fresh Ubuntu installation and a fresh OS X 10.11 installation on two separate machines. I followed the same procedure on Ubuntu and OS X however OS X will not link to other files within the project.

The error that I get on OS X is

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

The symbols in reference are symbols defined within the project itself. **Ubuntu works links and runs correctly without any change**. It is just OS X that will not link.

The exact method that I have used is written out in detail below. The question is: what is causing the OS X installation to fail to link? What differences are there between `g++-4.9` on Ubuntu versus OS X that may cause this issue? I installed `g++` using `apt-get` on Ubuntu and Homebrew on OS X - both are the exact same `g++` version. Both versions of `g++` appear to successfully link to header files in the C++ STL so it doesn't appear to be a compiler installation error. Any thoughts, comments or advice would be most appreciated.

These steps were repeated **identically** on both machines:

1) Clone repo from git into home directory
2) cd into repo
3) `make`

To show information about the compiler setup, I've included the output of `g++ -v` on both machines.

**Ubuntu**

`Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Ubuntu 4.9.3-8ubuntu2~14.04)`

**OS X**

`Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/4.9.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc49/4.9.3/lib/gcc/4.9 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog018 --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl011 --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc49 4.9.3' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.3 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.3)`

---

To add some more information, the symbols in question are defined in `sim/` and the code to compile is in `src/`. The Makefile is in `src` and is as below:

```
ROOT=`cd ../sim;pwd`
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x -g -O4 -fPIC -I$(ROOT)

lib: test.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared  -o libtest.so test.o
```

Comment: Hard to say. You need to check where the symbol is defined, see if the path to it's container is provided in gcc link command.

Comment: I've added the Makefile in question; as far as my understanding of Makefiles go, this should be including the directory of the missing symbols. It is including them on Ubuntu, just not OS X.

Comment: Make sure that you did not accidentally commit your .o file to the repository: you should remove the .o file and any other compiled binary on your Mac OS X machine just to be sure you are not accidentally trying to use  something you compiled on Ubuntu.  Did you really post the full output?  Maybe try adding the `-v` option for g++ in your Makefile so you can get more info about what's going on, and then post the full and exact output that you get from running `make`.

Comment: All .o files and other binaries have been cleaned and removed before attempting compilation. The full exact output from `make` is a list of 10 files that are defined in `../sim/` and that Ubuntu successfully links to. I can't share the exact printed output (function names) because it is not public information and is proprietary (this is a project that I am working on that is not mine to release). I've run it with `-v`; the output suggests that `g++` is including the correct directory `$(ROOT)`, but is not linking to the files.

Comment: Debugging Makefiles remotely is always hard - I'll appreciate any help or suggestions that you can provide.

Comment: Then I suggest removing code and simplifying your setup until you have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can share publicly.  Along the way you will probably discover what the problem is; if not then at least you have provided a way for other developers to reproduce your problem.  If you don't want to do that, it seems like you should at least be able to share with us the name of the file where x86_64 symbols are not found and the names of some of those symbols.

Comment: Another tip: just install Xcode and use the clang g++ it provides; I heard GCC on Mac is dead.  Homebrew, a popular package manager for Mac OS X, uses Xcode's toolchain to compile everything.  Don't hardcode the path to g++ in your Makefile; just invoke it as `g++` and expect a good compiler to be on your PATH.

Comment: Ah ha; you have stumbled onto the issue that plagued my entire day today. The project is exclusively developed on Linux and uses several features of GNU G++ that Clang does not support (variable length assignment is a big offended). I would prefer to use Clang but it will not compile this project, nor can the project be efficiently switched off its GCC only features; compiling GCC on OS X is difficult, but doable.  I'll see if I can't make a verifiable example.